# Регистрация без пароля - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины, пароль, регистрация

Подскажите, как сделать регистрацию без пароля на вордпресс? Так, чтобы пароль генерировался сам и отправлялся на почту уже после регистрации?

Comment: Вход через социальные сети мне не подходит.

Comment: Отправлять пароль почтой — плохо, потому что небезопасно.

Comment: WordPress при регистрации и не спрашивает пароль, а на почту отправляется не пароль, потому что небезопасно, как отметил @NickVolynkin, а ссылка для установки пароля (где он и генерируется). В чем вопрос-то? Сломать систему безопасности WordPress и слать пароль по почте?

Comment: бог ты мой) ну в ранних версиях вордпрес такое было, пароль отправлять по почте поверьте не опасно... вордпрес ломается и по другому.
у меня задача сделать регистрацию по имени и почте и все. ну и телефон может добавить.
пароль нужно чтобы отсылался на почту... 
прошу не писать мне что это не возможно или плохо) мне так нужно..

Comment: А чем не нравится этот вариант?
https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-email-login/

Comment: Я сейчас проверю данны плагин и отпишу, но боюсь это не работает для регистрации пользователя по почте, а только для  входа в систему.

Answer (score -1):

Можно использывать трюк со скрытыми полямы формы регистрации. Зачем так делать ? Потому, что потом декодировать пароль с MD5 почти нереально.

Суть: 
На странице регистрации скрить поле ввода пароля, но генерировать его вместо пользывателя(например через JS или PHP) и при сабмите к емейлу регистрации прикреплять значение даного поля.